# C# Select List of string from a anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the below LINQ, and I need the result returned as a List but I receive the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string emis>>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I return a List of strings?

```
List<string> emisList = (
    from p in subproductTypeyProduct
    join q in dbEntitiesParams.PARAM_Rule
    on new { p.ProductType, p.SubProductTypeCode }
    equals new { ProductType = q.ProductTypeCode, SubProductTypeCode = q.SubProductCode }
    select new { q.emis });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to project the anonymous type. Just the simple string. Replace `select new { q.emis }` with `select q.emis`.